# Plotting Time Stamp of Specific Format in matplotlib in python

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

**DD.MM_HH:MM:SS.mmmmmm**
 in this format **timestamps** are given so how to process them in **matplotlib** in python

I was trying to, but somehow it was only accepting arrays of floats. How can I get it to plot the time? Do I have to modify the format in any way?

I tried with this

`dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(list_of_datetimes)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date(dates, values)`

But getting the following error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.str_' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

Please provide the format which I should follow to parse this type of timestamp ?

Comment: Could you give an example of this timestamp?

Comment: 05.07_15:39:52.855866 this is the example of timestamp

Comment: And one more problem is how to provide spacing between y ticks when labels are very very large in number

Answer (score 0):

convert the strings in list_of_datetimes to `datetime` first:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib

# some example data:
list_of_datetimes = ['05.07_15:39:52.855866', '05.07_15:49:52.855866', '05.07_15:59:52.855866']
values = [1, 2, 3]

# to datetime:
dt = [datetime.strptime(s, '%d.%m_%H:%M:%S.%f') for s in list_of_datetimes]

dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(dt)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date(dates, values)
```

[image: datetime_on_xaxis]

An alternative could be plotting a timedelta since start on the x-axis to avoid issues with microsecond handling in `matplotlib`:

```
date = ["05.07_15:39:52.855866","05.07_15:39:52.855869","05.07_15:39:52.855988","05.07_15:39:52.855889"]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dt = [datetime.strptime(s, '%d.%m_%H:%M:%S.%f') for s in date]

# to timedelta:
td = [(d-dt[0]).total_seconds() for d in dt]

matplotlib.pyplot.plot(td, values)
```

[image: seconds_on_xaxis]

Comment: And one more problem there can u please help me out on this , how to provide spacing between y ticks when labels are very very large in number

Comment: @Ankur: did you have a look at [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html)?

Comment: I looked but data is too large in number

Comment: I looked but data is too large in number around 8000-10000 values are there

Comment: @Ankur: the problem seems to be the microseconds; are they of relevance to you?

Comment: actually I have to show them on plot so they are relavant to me sir

Comment: @Ankur: from what I can find, ´matplotlib` really has an issue with plotting microsecond accurate. An alternative I could think of would be to plot seconds since the first entry on the x-axis. Would that be an option?

Comment: Yes sir it will be best sorry for late reply